# my ChangeNotifierProvider doesn't work as cant be found correct provider

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-change-notifier

i have a problem with my ChangeNotifierProvider widget. my proivder cant be found so i cant update my target widget. there is similar errors that was solved but i cant understand the fixes as i am new on ChangeNotifier. So if you interested in help me, please tell clearly.

Here is my **error**:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this GamePage Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.
- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that GamePage is under your MultiProvider/Provider.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

  For example, instead of:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // Will throw a ProviderNotFoundError, because `context` is associated
      // to the widget that is the parent of `Provider<Example>`
      child: Text(context.watch<Example>().toString()),
    );
  }
  ```

  consider using `builder` like so:

  ```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      // we use `builder` to obtain a new `BuildContext` that has access to the provider
      builder: (context, child) {
        // No longer throws
        return Text(context.watch<Example>().toString());
      }
    );
  }
  ```

and here is my **Codes**:
*main.dart*

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  Adverter.initialization();
  runApp(MyInheritor(child: YirmiDortteDokuz()));

class YirmiDortteDokuz extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: '9in24 Game',
      theme: ThemeData(

      ),
      home: ChangeNotifierProvider( create: (BuildContext context) => Adverter(),
          child: MeetScreenPage()),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the route to *GamePage.dart* from *MeetScreenPage.dart*. there is no ChangeNotifierProvider stuff here and it extends StatefulWidget:

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
              GamePage(step: 0, pushes: [0], isRetry: false)));
```

Here is consumer builder and consumer widget in *GamePage.dart* class. it extends StatefulWdiget too.

```
class GamePageState extends State<GamePage>{
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Adverter _adverter = Provider.of<Adverter>(context, listen: false);
...
 Consumer<Adverter>(builder: (context, data, child) {
   return Text("Rewarded Point is ${_adverter.getrewardpoint()}");
 }),
}
```

And my *Adverter.dart* Class extends ChangeNotifier:

```
class Adverter extends ChangeNotifier{
 int _rewardedPoint = 0 ;
 int getrewardpoint() => _rewardedPoint;
...
 void showRewardedAd_second() {
    if (_rewardedAd == null) {
      return;
    }

    _rewardedAd.show(
        onUserEarnedReward: (RewardedAd ad, RewardItem rewardItem) {
          print("${rewardItem.amount} SANİYE KAZANILDI.");
          _rewardedPoint = _rewardedPoint + rewardItem.amount;

          notifyListeners();
        }
    );
    ...
  }
}
```

Please help and tell clearly to teach me. Thank you for your helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the type of `ChangeNotifierProvider` to `Adverter` like:

```
home: ChangeNotifierProvider<Adverter>(
  create: (BuildContext context) => Adverter(),
  child: MeetScreenPage()),
```

If you still can't access the provider, you can try to move it above `MaterialApp`, for example:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  Adverter.initialization();
  runApp(MyInheritor(child: YirmiDortteDokuz()));

class YirmiDortteDokuz extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Adverter>(
      create: (BuildContext context) => Adverter(),
      builder: (context, child) => MaterialApp(
        title: '9in24 Game',
        theme: ThemeData(),
        home: MeetScreenPage()),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, when defining your provider, use `with` instead of `extends`:

```
class Adverter with ChangeNotifier...
```

Comment: hello Peter. Thanks for your explaining and simple answer at first. i tried both of your solutions and second one is solve my problem little bit. i said "little bit" since it caused another problem. After i tried your second solution that makes MaterialApp child of ChangeNotifierProvider my correct error provider error has gone but  interstitial and rewarded ads **display problem** has came instead of it. Interstitial and rewarded ads can't be shown although they are both loaded and this error doesn't be seen as output. Just cant be shown. ++

Comment: ++ i can see them in other pages created with other classes but in GamePage class that i am using Notifier stuffs cant. i have waited for about 10 hours and tried again but same result. _if i remove notifier stuffs from everywhere, everything about admob service is normal._ So what is the reason of it and what must i do? My main problem is: updating reward and displaying it on GamePage. if there is another way from ChangeNotifier i can try.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I don't precisely understand your current problem, I am not familiar with admob. But if you wan't to display something in GamePage that comes from another widget, ChangeNotifierProvider is one of the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this...

This happens because you used a BuildContext that does not include the provider of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

You added a new provider in your main.dart and performed a hot-reload. To fix, perform a hot-restart.

The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.
```

**This error you was get because not define provider before used or improper use of provider**

Two way to solve

**first**

You must have to used  **ChangeNotifierProvider Or Provider or Similar** before you used provider for every state-full/stateless class.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => PrescriptionProvider(),
        builder: (context, child) {
        return YourWidget();
        });
}
```

But this is not good for multi-provider
We can user [MultiProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/MultiProvider-class.html) for multi provider or even single provider,

Advantages for used [MultiProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/MultiProvider-class.html) over my previous way (first way)

1. Need Declare only one time
2. All provider are in list
3. no need to used ChangeNotifierProvider with every widget (for used of provider)
4. used for single or [MultiProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/MultiProvider-class.html)

**How to used [MultiProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/MultiProvider-class.html)??**

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await sheredPref.initPref();
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => Adverter(),
        ),
      ... // other provider
      ],
      child: const MyApp(), //. as usual 
    ),
  );
}



class MyNewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // no need ChangeNotifierProvider after once you were declare in providers list
    final provider = context.watch<Adverter>(); // hope you know read vs watch in provider
    return Column(
      children: [],
    );
  }
}
```

**Hope this will help you**